# Can't Rails 3 run in MySQL MyISAM mode, without InnoDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have a MySQL server running with InnoDB disabled (for reasons of performance), with this setup I can't seem to be able to use Rails 3 (with the `mysql2` adapter).

Here's my test migration:

```
class CreateTxts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:txts, :options => 'ENGINE=MyISAM') do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And here's the error:

```
>rake db:migrate
rake aborted!
Mysql2::Error: Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB': CREATE TABLE `schema_migrations`
(`version` varchar(255) NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Tried the workaround described [here](http://blog.somekool.net/2009/04/08/how-to-make-rails-activerecord-migration-default-to-myisam), but it doesn't seem to work either (I did modify MysqlAdapter to Mysql2Adapter to match my setup).

Sorry I'm a newb in Rails. Any help will be much appreciated :o

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Going to answer my own question. Here's a patch for `environment.rb` I ended up with that works with the native mysql driver as well as JRuby/JDBC-mysql:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Patch Mysql adapter to default to MyISAM instead of InnoDB
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter'
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class MysqlAdapter
      def create_table(table_name, options = {}) #:nodoc:
        super(table_name, options.reverse_merge(:options => "ENGINE=MyISAM"))
      end
    end
  end
end

# Initialize the rails application
.....
```

`rake db:migrate` now succeeds and creates all tables including `schema_migrations` with TYPE=MyISAM.

Note: For mysql2 adapter, rename mysql_adapter to mysql2_adapter and MysqlAdapter to Mysql2Adapter.

Comment: You can write it shorter by replacing `module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class MysqlAdapter` with `class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter`

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the table without specifying the type of engine being used like this

```
class CreateTxts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:txts) do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and then in mysql cli, type this

```
ALTER TABLE txts ENGINE = MYISAM
```

hope it helps

Comment: I does not help, as InnoDB is disabled in my MySQL server. It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from creating the `schema_migrations` table (which rails uses to track which migrations have been run) rather than your table. You could create that table yourself (with a single varchar(255) column called `version` with an index on it).

If you do end up overwriting the `create_table` method, you need to preserve the method's signature - you're ignoring the block that it yields. I'd try something like

```
def create_table(name, options={})
  super(name, options.merge(...)) {|t| yield t}
end
```

Comment: No there is no yield block in the original MysqlAdapter's create_table :

Comment: Oops, got confused about behaviour of super there. Did you try creating the schema migrations table yourself?

Answer (score 0):

@rustyx nice one! &here's my slightly tweaked monkey-patch so the engine can be set from within the `/config/database.yml` configuration:

&Rather than in `/config/environment.rb`, i put the codes into an initializer, Eg: `/config/initializers/mysql2adapter_default_engine.rb`.

Either this for brevity:

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter'

class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter < ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::AbstractMysqlAdapter
  def create_table(table_name, options = {}) #:nodoc:
    super(table_name,  @config[:engine].nil? ? options : options.reverse_merge(:options => "ENGINE="+@config[:engine]))
  end
end
```

or this for more clarity:

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter'

module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class Mysql2Adapter < AbstractMysqlAdapter
      def create_table(table_name, options = {}) #:nodoc:
        super(table_name,  @config[:engine].nil? ? options : options.reverse_merge(:options => "ENGINE="+@config[:engine]))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in `/config/database.yml` we can have something like this:

```
production:
  adapter:  mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: ooook
  username: ooook
  password: ooook
  host:     ooook.tld
  port:     3306
  pool:     5
  timeout:  5000
  engine:   MyISAM
```

If no `engine` is specified then the `mysql2` adapter will use the default (`InnoDB` or whatever).